# Remove VIM search highlight

Tags: linux, vim, highlighting

After a search I've done, all the matches for the respective query remain highlighted and it's annoying. This happens even after I close the respective file (normal behavior?). How to I remove this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You want the command `:nohlsearch`, but you don't want to type that every time. Put this in your ~/.vimrc:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>n :nohlsearch<CR>
```

After that, you just enter your leader (which by default is `\`) and then `n` to clear the matches. You don't need to use `n`; if you prefer, pick something else.

You can also remap your leader to something more comfortable, if you like. I use a comma:

```
let mapleader = ","
```

(That goes *before* the mapping to clear searches.)

Comment: I just do :noh which is enough for vim to know what I mean. :)

Comment: @scottl Fair enough (and good reminder that all commands have shortcuts), but I still like to map frequently used commands.

Answer (score 11):

i just `/qiw772723euz` to "search" for something thats not in the file. hacky workaround, i know, i am interested in a real solution as well :)

Comment: thats awful but a nice quick and dirty 'solution' though :)

Answer (score 4):

Similar to @Telemachus answer above, a comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431184/macg-vim-highlight-all-occurrence-of-a-selected-word/3431203#3431203) over at SO by @David Winslow suggested mapping a toggle of `hlsearch`. You would map the following:

```
nmap <silent> <leader>n :set hlsearch!<CR>
```

Hitting n would then toggle highlight search off and on every time you hit it.

Answer (score 3):

In my config, I clear highlighted search terms by just **hitting enter in command mode**. This is how that's configured.

```
set hlsearch    " highlight all matched terms
" Pressing return clears highlighted search
:nnoremap <CR> :nohlsearch<CR>/<BS>
```

As a side note, I like to make sure that my search matches are highlighted **super clearly**, no matter the color scheme, so I give them black text on a yellow background.

```
" When highlighting search terms, make sure text is contrasting color
:highlight Search ctermbg=yellow ctermfg=black
" Do the same for gvim
:highlight Search guibg=yellow guifg=black
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a slightly different solution. To me it feels as the natural thing to do would be to press `<esc>` to make it go away. However, that doesn't work. Mapping `<esc>` to `:noh` has nasty side-effects, so that's not an option either. `<Leader>n` and similar mappings feels unintuitive for me for such a trivial task. However, pressing `<esc>` twice is something I can live with:

`nnoremap <silent> <esc><esc> :nohlsearch<CR>`