# vim colour issue

Tags: linux, vim, centos-6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove VIM search highlight](https://superuser.com/questions/173713/remove-vim-search-highlight)

In vim, when searching for a string (using `:/abc` for instance), it will become highlighted with yellow, like this:

[image]

After switching back to insert mode, the highlight will still be visible. How to make it disappear?

Comment: `:nohl` or `:nohlsearch`

Comment: `:nohl<CR>` not `:nohl whatever<CR>` (`<CR>` = return)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:nohl` or `:nohlsearch`. More information about these commands are found in the help: `:h nohl`.

It also makes sense to map `:nohl` to a key for quicker access, e.g.

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-l> :nohl<CR><C-l>
```